# How to find all invalid arguments in project?

Tags: php, php-8

I am working on migrating my project from php 7.4 to 8.1. Because of this, I constantly encounter the problem of incorrect arguments passed to the method.

For example: `count($data['items'])`, where `$data['items']` could potentially be an `array` or `null`.

Tried using `PHP_CodeSniffer` with `PHPCompatibility` with `--runtime-set testVersion 8.1` option.
But it doesn't detect such problems.

How can I find all such potential problems?

Comment: I don't know if there's a tool that can get you those specific errors always, but depending on how variables like `$data` are created, you might be able to type or type-hint them which could trigger such tools to report

Comment: [Rector](https://getrector.com/) might be helpful here.

Comment: @ChrisHaas can you explain detailer?

Comment: [PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/) _might_ be able to catch this case, if you use [docblock commenting](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types) to define what's expected in your array. But at that point, you're probably better off just making the edit to `count($data['items'] ?? [])`

Comment: @VD, if variables come from a function, the function's return type can be specified, and then calling `count` _might_ trigger a warning in tools: https://phpstan.org/r/328667b2-8da9-47b4-af61-2c2f32dd6b12. If returning just an array, you can added docblocks as Alex said to the function to describe the array. The other option is to turn on warnings in the error log for your 7.4 site and this will be picked up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result I filed to find a good solution for checking that the required data type is always passed to the function.

Rector, PHPStan, PHPCodeSniffer helped to check out some of the potential errors.
Other errors searched by manual testing.

Answer (score 1):

While not very advanced, but following the *error logs* from the server is pretty solid approach to remove all warnings.

*Error logs* are descriptive enough, that it tells the problem and its location. (or stacktrace if called by another functions/mediators).

In your example, already have a "flaw" in programming principle.

```
For example: count($data['items']), where $data['items'] could potentially be an array or null.
```

In the above, it is not PHP7 OR PHP8's compability problem that `count()` has been called on null and it gives you a warning.

The proper way to do it is to anticipate the possibility that variable is empty before you `count()`.

Here's what I mean:

```
$entries_found = ( !empty($data['items']) ? count($data['items']) : 0 );
```

Now you anticipate that it could be empty, so `count()` is not used if variable empty.

Similar approach need to be taken on most of the variables, so if they play any role later in the code, you know they either have **correct** value or **fallback** value.

Comment: If in php7.4 on count(null) generates warning in php8.1 will be fatall error. Currenly I'm looking through all project files checking where varialbles types may not match with expecting types and fixing like you mentioned. Its very exhausting. So i'm looking for linter or feature that can show me list of all potential mismatch. Thx for advice about logs, think that may help, but they minght not cower all usages.